# extract a color from an image with only Numpy without open CV

Tags: python, numpy

I want to extract a specific range of colors from an image represented by a Numpy array. Specifically, I would like to express the following equivalent code without using for statements.

```
lcol=np.array((23,22,174))
hcol=np.array((77,77,255))

def extract_color_from(img_array) : 
    height=np.shape(img_array)[0]
    width=np.shape(img_array)[1]
    for y in range(0,height) :
        for x in range(0,width) :
            for i in range(0,3) :
                if lcol[i]<img_array[y,x][i]<hcol[i] :
                    pass
                else :
                    img_array[y,x]=[0,0,0]
                    
    return img_array
```

I have tried to figure it out using the np.where and np.all functions, but it doesn't work.

```
lcol=np.array((23,22,174))
hcol=np.array((77,77,255))

def extract_color_from2(img_array) : 
    mask=np.all((lcol<=img) & (img<=hcol),axis=2) 
    ?????????????????
    ?????????????????
    return img_array
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that lcol and hcol are global variables and are defined as follows

lcol=np.array((23,22,174))
hcol=np.array((77,77,255

Comment: you can edit your post rather than adding forgotten clarifications as comments.

Comment: lookup `np.where`

Comment: You need a mask which is `(lcol < img_array) & (img_array < hcol)`. Anything other than that, you want to be zero. This is exactly what [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) does: Select from one array if a condition is `True`, and another (or a scalar) if a condition is `False`. And since it broadcasts over arrays, you can give it your mask array and your original image and get your output. For example, on a random `64x64` image, here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Lwvw.png). What did you try with `np.where`? `all` is not the way here.

Comment: Should I replace the code with something like the following? 
    mask=np.where((lcol<=img) & (img<=hcol), xxxx, [0,0,0])
If so, what should I put in the xxxx part?